# NSObject class not found when try to import another NSObject class

Tags: ios7, nsobject

I have 2 `NSObjectclass`s I want to import one class to the other one. but when I import it. it says class not found. What should be the reason for this?

Thanks

This is my .h class

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Ride : NSObject
{
NSString *strRide_id;
NSString *strRide_name;
NSString *strOrigin_city;
NSString *strStreet_address;
NSString *strOrigin_zip;
NSString *strOrigin_country;
NSString *strRide_cover_image;
double dblRide_price;
NSString *strCurrency_type;
NSString *strUser_id;
NSString *strUser_first_name;
NSString *strUser_last_name;
NSString *strUser_profile_image;
NSMutableArray *mutArrayride;
}


@end
```

Comment: Did you rename a class NSObject, or do you have two classes that are subclasses of NSObject causing problems?

Comment: can we see some code to clear

Comment: yes I have 2 sub classes from NSObject

Comment: I updated the code,, and I import like this #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> #import "JSON.h"
#import "Engine.h"
#import "Ride.h"